# Is it possible to call bulit in Camera app to save to external storage?

Tags: android, camera

Hello i'm new to android.

I want to call the built in Camera app as a whole. Like I want my application to call that application to take some pictures, then it will save to external storage by itself like how when the user clicks on the camera in the menu. I'm not looking for incorporating the camera in my application. I just want to call it and let it do it's job.

I have researched a bit and only found examples and people asking questions of incorporating camera in their application. Please help me, thanks.

Currently I have this in my code, but it looks like it's incorprating it into the code. I just want call it and let it save to the external storage like normally when a user press the camera app.

```
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you mean by incorporating.  Take a look at the [Android Developer Docs on using existing camera apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)

Comment: incorporating is when i use "onActivityResult".

Comment: I want to call the camera with just "startactivity". Like when someone clicks on the camera button on the android menu.

Comment: and normally by default it saves on external storage. When i plan to retrieve  from an image selector app that i made.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're not incorporating the camera in your code, you just calling the camera app to take a photo for you.

From the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

> An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

You can request the Camera App to save the photo in a path of choice using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT key.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriToFileInExternalStorage);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

see here: [MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT)

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            //2
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
            mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            //3
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            //4
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                //5
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed, Thanks for replying. Can you explain what is "mImage"?

Comment: Sure. Its an ImageView

Comment: I had to initialize mImage near the top.  Then the warning went away. Then i ran it and when i finish taking a picture it doesn't save and applications stops working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm, null, null);

            }
```

I ended up using this after the result came in and it works :)